# Dump value of register using frida

Tags: disassembly, windows, debugging, functions, frida

I'm new with frida and came to this problem.

I have dll that I want to reverse engeneer(there are no debug symbols). Specifically I want to dump some data from a function. So I have this big function and here is the fragment of it:

[image]

Here you can see that some string(`pf4`) is moved to `edx`, but more important thing comes after that. You can see that `sub_575FD30`
function is called couple of times.

The most interesting thing for me is the `eax` register after the call. So what I want to do is to dump value of `eax` after the call of this function.

I can't consider dumping something from `sub_575FD30` function because that function is called from many other places and I specifically want to dump `eax` after calling it in this specific example.

My question is how can I acheive it using frida? Should I hardcode the instruction address(address of `push eax`) and get value of `eax`? Is it the correct way or is there some better way to achieve it? Any direction of how to achieve it and script example would be appriciated.

Comment: why cant you dump from the function ? you always have the return address when you are in the function why cant you discard return values other than 659,66a etc

Comment: Thank! That is a good point! Can you give me direction or example similar to that script to get me started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Details are all available in the [Javascript API documentation for Interceptor](https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/)

below is a small demo

assuming you have a source code as below the adder function will be called from 3 places 
for a total of 26 times

```
#include <stdio.h>
int adder( int a , int b) {
    return a+b;
}
int addonce (int a, int b) {
    return adder(a,b);
}
int addtwice (int a, int b) {
    return adder(a,b) + adder (a,b);
}
int addntimes(int a, int b, int c) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++ ) {
        res = res + adder(a,b);
    }
    return res;
}
void main(void) {
    getchar();
    printf("%d\n", addonce(2,3));
    printf("%d\n", addtwice(2,3));
    printf("%d\n", addntimes(2,3,10));
    printf("%d\n", addonce(2,3)+addtwice(2,3)+addntimes(2,3,10));
}
```

compiled with vs 2017 community  and executed

```
cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od /EHsc mulcall.cpp /link / release 
5
10
50
65
```

Frida python script

```
import frida
import sys

session = frida.attach("mulcall.exe")
script = session.create_script("""
Interceptor.attach
(
    ptr("%s"),
    {
        onEnter: function(args) 
        {
            console.log("entering  intercepted function will return to " + this.returnAddress);
        } ,
        onLeave: function(retval)
        {
            console.log( "leaving intercepted function returning " + retval.toInt32());
        }
    }
);
""" % int(sys.argv[1], 16))

def on_message(message, data):
    print(message)
script.on('message', on_message)
script.load()
sys.stdin.read()
```

you need the address of adder function that you have to pass (in your case the 5xxx address of sub_yyyy) be aware ASLR may come into play you always need a fresh address of the running instance not some stale address of past instances

you will run the script like this

```
python friscript.py 7ff670901000
```

the 0x00007ff670901000 is the address of adder() for me
I have executed the exe and it is waiting for a keypress 
now I run the above script 
it attaches and waits until I press a key in the waiting instance

here is the output of Frida

```
python friscript.py 7ff670901000
entering  intercepted function will return to 0x7ff670901039
leaving intercepted function returning 5
entering  intercepted function will return to 0x7ff670901069
leaving intercepted function returning 5
entering  intercepted function will return to 0x7ff67090107a
leaving intercepted function returning 5
entering  intercepted function will return to 0x7ff6709010d4
leaving intercepted function returning 5 (10 times)
entering  intercepted function will return to 0x7ff670901039
leaving intercepted function returning 5
entering  intercepted function will return to 0x7ff670901069
leaving intercepted function returning 5
entering  intercepted function will return to 0x7ff67090107a
leaving intercepted function returning 5
entering  intercepted function will return to 0x7ff6709010d4
leaving intercepted function returning 5 (10 times)
```

EDIT to address Comment

if eax is a pointer to some type (ansi,wide,utf8,utf16,bytearray,struct *)

use the appropriate helper function  in onLeave {}
here is an implementation for a function returning a struct *
struct { int a , char * b }

```
  // hack for getting the next member of struct  (adding pointer size  of 
  // 32bit machine read documents to see if you can cast the return 
  // value to proper structure type 
  // so that we can use (foo *) (this.context.eax)->a 
  // instead of hacks like add(4) 

  foo = Memory.readPointer(this.context.eax.add(4)) 
  blah = Memory.readCString(foo)
  log( blah )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for an answer ! One more question please, how can I log the value of eax? `this.context.eax` seems to print the address

Comment: and it seems like it is a unicode string because it's something like L"<string>"