# Read and write to register with Frida

Tags: ios, register, frida, arm64, aarch64

I have an instruction that looks like this in Ghidra:

```
       100168ff0 e9 13 00 32     orr        w9,wzr,#0x1f
```

Using `lldb` I can set a breakpoint on the instruction after this, read `w9` to confirm what value it is storing and modify it if needs be.

I am trying to do something similar with Frida with the following script:

```
var t_module = 'testApp';
var loadAddress = Module.getBaseAddress(t_module);
var instructionOffset = ptr(0x168ff4);

var toAtt = loadAddress.add(instructionOffset);

Interceptor.attach(toAtt, {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        console.log("[+] Module base address found at " + loadAddress)
        console.log("[+] Found instruction at " + toAtt)
        console.log("[+] Attempting to read w9: " + this.context.w9)
    }
});
```

however trying to read `w9` just returns `undefined`.  It is defined [here](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#aarch64-enum-types) so is not that Frida is calling it something else.

I can confirm the right address is being reached using:

```
Memory.readByteArray(ptr("0x102ab4ff0"),4)
```

where `0x102ab4ff0` is the address printed by the script, and comparing it to the instruction at the beginning from Ghidra.

I'm not sure if I've misunderstood something about Frida or where I should attach. [This](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21701/dump-value-of-register-using-frida) is the closest question I could find and that just says to use `this.context.eax`.

Comment: did you see any of your logs from `onEnter`? ( also, you don't need to `.add` a `ptr`, you can just add the offset using `.add(0x11)`. there is no `eax` in arm64 ) to answer your question please print `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.context))`

Comment: Thank you very much @whoopdedoo! This suggestion helped me work out the problem.

The comment about eax was more to illustrate that that was what I understood to be the correct way to address a register as opposed to eax being used by arm64, I am a complete RE n00b though so it was a fair assumption to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that `w9` is a 32-bit register and I was using a 64 bit device.  By calling `this.context.x9` for the 64 bit register the Frida script worked perfectly.  Many thanks to @whoopdedoo, their suggestion to log `this.context` was what led me to search more about ARM registers and realise my mistake.